# Python-Selenium-Chrome minimized window is maximizing itself

Tags: python, windows, selenium, testing, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium with chromedriver in Python for testing 2 functionalities in parallel. Basically my webpage have 2 dropdown menus. Choosing an option from any dropdown menu will download a file. I have 2 scripts testing both dropdown menus separately. Now let say script-1 opens chrome and load the webpage. Now script-1 opens the dropdown-1 and it is in process of selecting an option from it as per the given input. During this if I navigate away from opened webpage to any other window eg. file explorer, the dropdown will get close without choosing the option and test case hangs. Also if I minimize the window before the dropdown is opened, the window will reopen itself when option is clicked for downloading the file. How can I stop the window from re-opening. Is there any Chrome setting for this?

Even if I move away from computer during execution, I want to run both the scripts in parallel side by side as they both open separate windows but after sometime one of them hangs the other window and I have to manually click on dropdown to bring it back to life. I am planning to run the scripts using multithreading with 2 threads referring to each of the scripts.

Note : I cannot use urlretrieve as there is no pre-defined URL for the files in webpage. PhantomJS do not support file download.

I am using Windows 10 machine.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this

1. Run the parallel test using selenium grid and multiprocess, you could do this easily in docker, using docker/selenium, reference for using docker in https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium
2. Disable save dialog in chrome

   ```
   options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
   options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
     "download.default_directory": r"yourpath",
     "download.prompt_for_download": False
   })
   DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();

   driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
   ```

Comment: I have already disabled the save dialog. I will look into docker and let you know.